# How to filter the string patterns to match in textlines with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I need match this regular expression pattern in the given text with python.

The text is :

```
  """

       2010 Toyota FJ Cruiser FJ CRUISER

       Int. Color:

       Ext. Color:

       Black

       Trans:

       Automatic

       VIN:

        JTEZU4BF7AK009445  


      Stock:

      122821B

      DIFFERENTIALBLACK

     Status:

     Body Style: 
     SUV
     Engine:
     Gas V6 4.0L/241
                                             Dealership: Universal Toyota



    $29,988*
                                             Price

     View More Information


     Compare?

    """
```

From this text i need to extract "JTEZU4BF7AK009445" (length is 17) this pattern after vin: probably

I used this pattern

```
        vin_pattern = re.compile('([A-Z0-9]{17})')
        vin = re.findall(vin_pattern,text)

        ["JTEZU4BF7AK009445","DIFFERENTIALBLACK"]
```

But *DIFFERENTIALBLACK* should not be matched

As well as I used also the pattern

```
       price_pat = re.compile('(\$[0-9\,\.]+)')
```

to match the price range ("$"sign+value)

Here I need to check this price matching pattern **only before and after 50 characters** of **VIN_PATTERN** appears.
Because in some cases i have more price values.So, i need to filter the text before 50 characters and after 50 characters of that VIN pattern exists

Plz How it should supposed to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's first simplify your text a bit by normailizing all whitespaces to a single space symbol:

```
t2 = re.sub(r'[\n\t\ ]+', ' ', t)  # t is your original text
```

It makes looking for a VIN much easier task:

```
re.findall('[A-Z]{3}[A-Z0-9]{10}[0-9]{4}', t2)
Out[2]: ['JTEZU4BF7AK009445']
```

Then you can get position of VIN: in your string and pass vin_position - 50, vin_position + 50 into .findall method:

```
r2 = re.compile('(\$[0-9\,\.]+)')
r2.findall(t2, t2.find('VIN:') - 50, t2.find('VIN:') + 50)
Out[4]: []
```

In your text the price is more than 50 chars from VIN, i.e. you need to extend this boundary (100 works just fine):

```
r2.findall(t2, t2.find('VIN:') - 100, t2.find('VIN:') + 100)
Out[5]: ['$29,988']
```

Comment: +1 since it's the only answer that takes the -50/+50 characters into account.

Comment: Dude thanks for the solution. In matching the "VIN:" pattern,we should have to insert the constraints  "VIN:([A-Z0-9]{17})" + "NUMERIC SHOULD APPEAR ALONG WITH ALPHABETS" instead of "VIN:" with length is 17. Since, that "VIN:" might not be appear for some cases

Comment: @saravana, can you use something like this? re.findall('[A-Z]{3}[A-Z0-9]{10}[0-9]{4}', t2)

Comment: re.findall('[A-Z]{3}[A-Z0-9]{10}[0-9]{4}', t2),Here First three digits should be alphabets,so it is violating.the rules are 1)Total length is 17 digits 2)last 3 digits minimum should be numbers 3)Two alphabets must be present So, Here the two alphabets must be present but it might be presents anywhere. How should i do that two alphabets must be present in the pattern?

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have to use regexes (they are a pain in the a**) i would recommend following solution:

```
yourstr = """ ... whatever ... """

lst = yourstr.split()
vin = lst[lst.index('VIN:') + 1]
price = [i for i in lst if '$' in i][0]
```

I hope this will be sufficient!

Answer (score 1):

A dirty hack but it will work.

```
import re
st = "....your string...."
x = re.findall(r"VIN:([^Stock]+)",st)
y = "".join(x)
y.strip(" \n")
print y
```

output = `'JTEZU4BF7AK009445'`